# A Proxy that encrypts your data is the same thing as a VPN?

Tags: vpn, proxy

I have heard that a VPN encrypts your data but a proxy doesn't.

So a proxy that encrypts your data is the same thing as a VPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Virtual Private **Network*** VPN works at the network layer, and you could use it to route any network traffic, while a *proxy* could be many things. E.g. a SOCKS proxy proxies TCP connections and an SSH tunnel could be used for similar purposes than a VPN, but you are more likely referring to a HTTP proxy, that forward HTTP request. Nevertheless, proxy with an encryption doesn't equal a VPN, and technically they are two very different things.

Comment: Thank you, i dont really understand, both proxy and vpn can route the network traffic and encrypt your data

Comment: @Zheer: you can both use a bike or a car to transport things. This does not mean that a bike and a car are the same. VPN and proxies have __some__ use cases in common, but they are not the same and they don't have __all__ use cases in common.

Comment: Exactly, and a bike with an engine is still not a car (a moped at most), despite you can now use it for transportation without all the pedaling.